# Not able to click on the Continue button. It is clicking the other button

Tags: selenium, protractor

I want to click on the continue button. But when I am trying to do that it is hitting the Cancel button. When I am taking the xpath for continue button and hitting chrome console, its showing the continue button. But in selenium or protractor its hitting the cancel button.

[image]

Comment: show us the code and xpath you have tried so far ?

Comment: Which selector do you currently use?

Comment: element(by.css(".confirm")).click();

Comment: if you do element(by.css(".confirm")).getText().then(function (t){console.log(t)}); what does it show? I'm beginning to wonder if you are finding the right button, but the click itself is wired wrong or failing.Or does element(by.css(".confirm")).getAttribute('outerHTML').then(function (t){console.log(t)});  yield surprises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for protractor try this, should work correctly

```
element(by.buttonText('Continue!')).click();
```

Comment: Error I am getting with this:

Started
FA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.


Failures:
1) angularjs homepage should greet the named user
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

Answer (score 0):

Use ccs selector:

```
element(by.css(’button.confirm’))
```

Comment: Can you explain further how to use that CSS selector within Protractor?

Comment: Error: 

Failures:
1) angularjs homepage should greet the named user
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

Answer (score 0):

Select the element by css and click it:

```
 element(by.css(".confirm")).click();
```

Comment: I am getting this error

Failures:
1) angularjs homepage should greet the named user
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)

Comment: @JonyD add in conf.js file:  exports.config = {

    defaultTimeoutInterval: 2000000,

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails try xpath, do note it'll of course be brittle if your application is multi-lingual

```
element(by.xpath("//*[text()='Continue']")).click();
```